# Issues in converting JSON to XML

Tags: java, xml, json

I am writing a code in which I am converting my JSON to XML. The code for conversion is:

```
        BufferedReader in;
        try {
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/Users/appleBud/json");

         jsonData = IOUtils.toString(is);

         System.out.println("json data is: "+jsonData);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer();
        JSON json = JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonData);

        String xml = serializer.write(json);
        System.out.println(xml);
```

I am able to generate the XML. However, my JSON contains HTML code which it is unable to display in the respective format. For eg, '<' becomes &lt and '>' becomes '&gt' in my XML. I tried to use different solutions available but none solved my issue.

My JSON is something like:

```
 {
    "title":"<p>This is demo </p>",
    "index":"<li>Demo1</li><li>Demo2</li>",
     "name": "KB649364539",
     "creationDate": "Wed Aug 07 2013 00:00:52 GMT+0000"
}
```

and the corresponding XML generated is:

```
<title type="string">&lt;p&gt;This is demo&lt;/p&gt;</title>
<index type="string">&lt;li&gt;Demo1&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Demo2&lt;/li&gt;</index>
```

Expected Output is:

```
<title><p>This is demo</p></title>
<index><li>Demo1</li><li>Demo2</li></index>
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: so what's your Json looks like ?

Comment: '<' becomes '&lt;' and '>' becomes '&gt;' **THIS IS NOT AN ERROR**, this is how it show be

Comment: why not converting the Json into Java objects and then converting it to XML? You may be able to control the content easily.

Comment: Can you show an example of your input, output and expected output?

Comment: Underscore-java has a static method U.jsonToXml(json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the HTML escape characters, it will work fine:)

```
public static String filterDecode(String url){

   url = url.replaceAll("&amp;", "&")
     .replaceAll("&lt;", "<")
     .replaceAll("&gt;", ">")
     .replaceAll("&apos;", "\'")
     .replaceAll("&quot;", "\"")
     .replaceAll("&nbsp;", " ")
     .replaceAll("&copy;", "@")
     .replaceAll("&reg;", "?");
   return url;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Bob. It worked but faced another issue. My XML just created a tag like <content type="string">. Can you help me out on this? I don't want the type to be a part of my tag.

Comment: I advise you to integrate some XML operating API into your project, e.g. DOM4J, SAX. Usually it provides lots of convenient method of for DOM operation. otherwise you'll have to replace and replace.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use JSON.org , which is quite easy to use just doing this:

```
import org.json.XML;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(your string or file *.json);
System.out.println(XML.toString(jsonObj);
```